# How to add folders to git repository?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I would like to publish some project I created with java ,about MMU.
The project folder actually contains two separate folders: the first one is for the client, and the second one for the server.

Of course, to achieve that goal , the first step  is to create a new repository in my own GitHub site. So I did.

Then, I was trying tried the following to add the relevant folders in this repository:

1) **Directly through GitHub :**

I clicked on my repository in a browser, then I clicked on Upload Files. However, uploading an entire folder so that GitHub would preserve the hierarchy of the files and folders in my folder - is failed , since it can not select folders to be uploaded.

I also was trying to drag and drop the folders, but it always got the following error : `" Yowza, that’s a big file. Try again with a file smaller than 25MB."` ,even though the files I wish to upload are well under 25MB.

2) **By using git-bash command line:**

According to this link https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/How-to-upload-an-entire-folder/td-p/8516, typing the following commands should fulfill the goal of adding entire folders into a repository:

```
git init

git add <folder1> <folder2> <etc.>

git commit -m "Your message about the commit"

git remote add origin https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepository.git

git push -u origin master

git push origin master
```

but after I type the command : git add   , I get the following error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
```

How do you add entire folders into a repository then?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `<folder1>` refers to a random folder. If the folder's name is `foo`, use `git add foo` instead of `git add <foo>`.

Comment: You can try this tutorial for basics http://schacon.github.io/git/gittutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the tutorial says `<folder1>`, just use the folder name without `<` `>`, i.e. `folder1`, not `<folder1>`. `<folder1>` is just a placeholder for your folder.

For example, if I wanted to add `my_cool_folder`, I'd do the following:

```
git add my_cool_folder
git commit -m "I added my_cool_folder"
git push
```

Answer (score 4):

- git init
- git add project_folder
- git commit -m "Adding new Project"
- git remote add origin https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepository.git
- git push -u -f origin master

Go to the local repository where project_folder is present. Execute these commands which will add project_folder inside yourRepository on github.com.

Answer (score 0):

1) `git init`

2) `git add client server` (client and server are the folder 1 and folder2)

3) `git commit -m "added client and server folders"`

Rest of the steps are same.